# Replace a specific character in Jenkins shell step

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a variable `$svn_tag` in a Jenkins job.

Its value is `branches/sprint-77`.

I want the output `branches-sprint-77`, but I didn't get any output.

I tried these two methods:

```
$svn_tag|tr "/" -
${svn_tag////-}
```

It is giving output in bash script, but it is not working in the Jenkins job.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both of these also won't work in a Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach does not make sense, not the least because you try to run `$svn_tag´ as a command. Your second approach works for me:

```
 svn_tag=branches/sprint-77
 echo ${svn_tag////-}
```

prints *branches-sprint-77*.

For the safe side, you could also check your bash version, by doing a

```
echo bash=$BASH_VERSION
```

though I don't think that this feature is version-dependent. Mine is *4.4.12(3)-release*.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using it as a command and it worked. `$svn_tag|tr "/" -`

Comment: `$svn_tag|tr "/" - ` does not make sense. I think you mean `echo $svn_tag|tr "/" - ` or better `tr / - <<<$svn_tag`. However, isn't it a waste of resources creating a child process, if it can be done equally well in the parent process? But of course this is up to you....

Answer (score 0):

Use code like below

```
${svn_tag.replaceAll('/', '-')}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).